# I'll chase this up for you and I'll let you know at my earliest opportunity.

Tags: grammar

is this sentence correct? Please let me know what you think

Answer (score 1):

I would use "I will **follow up** on this and get back to you as soon as possible."

Comment: However, the original sentence is grammatical.